# Changing the fonts with "Century Gothic" in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fonts, font-size

I want to change the font to Century Gothic, I had some explanations and fixing but I got nothing, Im a newbie :) .. like

```
1 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Century-Gothic.ttf");
2 TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView0);
3 tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

To use custom font for android app follow this steps

1- Add the custom font inside `assets` folder

2- Define the font

```
Typeface myfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context,"myfont.ttf");
```

Now you can use `myfont` for `textview`

```
mytextview.setTypeface(myfont);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in android studio 3.1.3:

1. Copy the font inside font folder.
2. Select the font on fontFamily attributes.